# How to trigger keyup with enter key

Tags: unit-testing, vue.js, ava

When writing unit tests with [`ava`](https://github.com/avajs/ava) and `vuejs` how can I trigger the `Enter` keyup event?

For example, with the following component how can I test that `someFunction` has been called?

```
<input
  @keyup.enter="someFunction"
/>
```

Answer (score 4):

I've found on [vue-test-utils docs](https://vue-test-utils.vuejs.org/guides/dom-events.html). I need to call `input.trigger('keyup.enter');`

Here is a full example:

```
test('it should call add mutation', t => {
  const wrapper = mount(Todo, { localVue, store: createStore() });
  const input = wrapper.find('.todo-value');

  input.setValue('New todo item');
  input.trigger('keyup.enter');

  t.true(mutations.add.called);
});
```